# getUserTriggers() Returns Empty Array Even Though Trigger Exists

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a weird problem. I am trying to understand how this trigger function actually works in Gapps:
getUserTriggers()
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getusertriggersspreadsheet

I am using this very simple piece of code used as script within a spreadsheet:

```
function testing(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('some id');
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getUserTriggers(ss);
  // Log the event type for the first trigger in the array.
  Logger.log(triggers[0].getHandlerFunction())
}
```

At the same time, I have manually scheduled this function to run every hour and I see it on the list of "My Triggers" under https://script.google.com/u/0/home/triggers. Everything is done from 1 account (script creation, script scheduling)

The thing is that when I run the function, it returns 0 items in the array and I would expect 1 item in the array - the trigger which I've created manually and the one which I see in https://script.google.com/u/0/home/triggers for this file.

So the question is - how come I am getting 0 items and not 1 item?

All I'm getting is *"TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHandlerFunction' of undefined (line 5, file "Code")"*

DZ

Comment: Try `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`

Comment: Already tried, no difference...

Comment: What about `getProjectTriggers()`?

Comment: getProjectTriggers() works ok.

Answer (score 2):

As written in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getusertriggersspreadsheet),

> Gets all installable triggers owned by this user in the given spreadsheet, for this script or add-on only

It only returns triggers for the Spreadsheet, i.e., triggers based on [Spreadsheet Trigger Builder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder): like `edit` , `open`.

For other triggers, use [`getProjectTriggers()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getprojecttriggers) instead.

Comment: Sorry, but I am still failing to understand the wording and how you deduct that getUserTriggers() returns only edit, open etc. when the documentation says what you pasted above "... in the given spreadsheet, for this script or add-on only..." - I'd expect I would still get 1 item based on the description in the documentation.

Comment: @DanielZrust I agree the wording is unclear. Basically "in the given spreadsheet" is key. Time triggers are not in the spreadsheet though the function it triggers may be in the spreadsheet's bound script. Contrast this with `edit` installable trigger, where the `edit` is `in` the `spreadsheet`.

Comment: I didn't know that, it seems like a strange explanation given by google on that.