# what is the correct way to install a timeBased() trigger for a Google Sheets private (domain-wide) add-on?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

I have deployed a bound Google Sheets private add-on (domain-wide) and would like to utilize a timeBased() trigger to run a single function every 1 to 24 hrs. The add-on will be used for ‘n’ sheet installs and is currently running on 3 installs and the ‘master’ sheet (where the code resides and is deployed from).

**The trigger installs from an add-on menu function which should:**

- Checks to see if the trigger exists on the current spreadsheet
- Provides prompts based on true/false
- The trigger already exists would you like to reset it?
- What time increment would you like to set.
- Returns a success alert

**Desired results:**

- To have the trigger available for each of the spreadsheets running the add-on. So, spreadsheet1 could have the trigger set to run every 2 hours,
  while spreadsheet2 runs every 2 hours.
- Ability to change the trigger time for the current spreadsheet by deleting
  the current trigger and installing a new one.

**Actual results of the trigger after installing:**

- I am not able to identify the current spreadsheet to install or delete the trigger isolated to that unique spreadsheet.
- I am not able to install the same trigger for each sheet that is running the add-on.
- The trigger is not installing as a userTrigger. Or at least I am not getting anything back when I call getUserTriggers() on the respective spreadsheets.
- When I install the trigger from any of my sheets for the first time
  using the menu function as described above it seems to install and
  run as expected.
- When I install the trigger for the second sheet in that sheet’s respective menu, it ‘sees’ the trigger that was installed in the first sheet ( I am logging out the trigger Id ) as if it is installed in the current (second) sheet. *(this is apparently because I am using getProjectTriggers() which is getting all of the projects triggers regardless of which sheet is running the script)*.

**Additional information:**

- The function that is supposed to trigger on this schedule is
  manipulating data from a sheet within the install that will have been
  updated by a stand-alone script and placing this data in several
  different sheets.
- I am the only user on the domain currently accessing the sheets. The
  developer email from the GCP dashboard has been changed to be
  admin@mydomain.com instead of my personal email.

**Current scopes in the Google Cloud Platform Dashboard:**

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

The Add-on is also whitelisted in admin.google.com.

**This is what I am using to install the trigger:**

```
function installUpdateTrigger() {

  const documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  const currentSsId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  //documentProperties.setProperty('SHEET_ID', currentSsId);
  
  Logger.log('Sheet Name: ' + documentProperties.getProperty('sheet_name'));
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(documentProperties.getProperty('SHEET_ID'));
  //const allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  const userTriggers = ScriptApp.getUserTriggers(ss);
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const lastRan = documentProperties.getProperty('UPDATE_FEEDS_LAST_RAN');
  const lastChecked = documentProperties.getProperty('UPDATE_FEEDS_LAST_CHECKED');
  const authInfo = ScriptApp.getAuthorizationInfo(ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL);
  
  const userTriggersArrayBefore = getAllUserTriggers();
  const triggersIdArrayBefore = getAllTriggerIds();
  const triggerNamesBefore = getAllTriggerNames();
  
  Logger.log('triggersIdArrayBefore: ' + triggersIdArrayBefore);
  Logger.log('InstallationSource: ' + ScriptApp.getInstallationSource());
  Logger.log('authRequired: ' + authInfo.getAuthorizationStatus());
  Logger.log('userTriggers: ' + userTriggers);
  
  
  if (userTriggersArrayBefore.indexOf('updateFeeds') < 0 || userTriggersArrayBefore == 'undefined') {    
    const response = ui.prompt('Enter the update frequency. A whole # between 1-24 (hours)', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    const responseNumb = response.getResponseText();
    
// To-do: Do something with 'Cancel'
    
    documentProperties.setProperty('UPDATE_FEEDS', responseNumb);
    
    Logger.log('responseNumb (set): ' + responseNumb);
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('updateFeeds')
      .timeBased()
      .everyHours(responseNumb)
      .create();
      
      Logger.log('triggersIdArrayAfterSet: ' + getAllTriggerIds());
      
      ui.alert('The trigger has been created');

  } else {
      const currentTriggerInterval = documentProperties.getProperty('UPDATE_FEEDS');
      const responseYesNo = ui.alert('Feed trigger update', 'A trigger is already set to run every ' + currentTriggerInterval + 
                                     ' hour(s), would you like to reset it? ' 
                                     + '\r\n' + '\r\n Last checked: ' + lastChecked 
                                     + '\r\n Last ran: ' + lastRan, 
                                     ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    
      if (responseYesNo == ui.Button.YES) {
        const response = ui.prompt('Update trigger', 'Enter the update frequency. A whole # between 1-24 (hours)', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
        const responseNumb = response.getResponseText();
        documentProperties.setProperty('UPDATE_FEEDS', responseNumb);
        
        ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[triggerNamesBefore.indexOf('updateFeeds')]);
        Logger.log('responseNumb (reset): ' + responseNumb);
        ScriptApp.newTrigger('updateFeeds')
                 .timeBased()
                 .everyHours(responseNumb)
                 .create(); 
        
        Logger.log('triggersIdArrayAfterReset: ' + getAllTriggerIds());
        ui.alert('The trigger has been updated');
    }
  }

}




function getAllTriggerIds() {
  const allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  const triggersIdArray = [];
  for (i=0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
    const triggerId = allTriggers[i].getUniqueId();
    Logger.log('triggerId: ' + triggerId);
//    Logger.log('triggerSource: ' + ScriptApp.getInstallationSource());
    triggersIdArray.push(triggerId);
  }
 return triggersIdArray;

}




function getAllUserTriggers() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const userTriggers = ScriptApp.getUserTriggers(ss);
  const userTriggersArray = [];
  for (i=0; i < userTriggers.length; i++) {
    const userTrigger = userTriggers[i];
    Logger.log('userTrigger: ' + userTrigger);
//    Logger.log('triggerSource: ' + ScriptApp.getInstallationSource());
    userTriggersArray.push(triggerId);
  }
  
  Logger.log('userTriggersArray: ' + userTriggersArray);
 return userTriggersArray;

}



function getAllTriggerNames() {
  const allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  const triggerNameArray = [];
  for (i=0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
    const triggerName = allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction();
    Logger.log('triggerName: ' + triggerName);
    triggerNameArray.push(triggerName);
  }
 return triggerNameArray;

}
```

**Outstanding question(s):**

- How can I tell which spreadsheet a timeBased() trigger is associated with when using in an add-on?

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't you provide code related to how "it ‘sees’ the trigger that was installed in the first sheet"?

Comment: @TheMaster - Yes, I should have included that. The post now has all of the code that is setting the trigger and logging the results. I am seeing the results of the logs at https://script.google.com/home/executions.

Comment: Why not use [getUserTriggers()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getusertriggersspreadsheet)?

Comment: my bad. I didn't catch getUserTriggers() wasn't returning anything in the logs. Changing ss to getActive() instead of getActiveSpreadsheet() apparently prevented that from logging out. I have updated it on my end but ultimately getUserTriggers() returns nothing. Which is one reason why I am assuming that is my issue.

Comment: Could you [edit] to show the latest script? I assumed your problem was "seeing" the triggers. This is true for `getprojecttriggers`. But `getUserTriggers()` should only return user triggers as you've intended. So problem should have been solved.

Comment: I have updated the script to be my latest 'attempt' and also added some more information as to my desired result. Thank you for your help as my misunderstanding of how this is supposed to work is skewing my ability to ask the correct question(s).

Comment: Does this clarify some of your questions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63713929/getusertriggers-returns-empty-array-even-though-trigger-exists/63714205#comment112668235_63714205

Comment: Yes, that helps thank you. So, if I am understanding correctly, timeBased() triggers are not set at the spreadsheet level, they are set at the project level. Therefore, to accomplish my desired outcome I will need to get the trigger ID as it is created/installed and store it somewhere (probably documentProperties) and then test against that when resetting the trigger time intervals?

Comment: Yup That's the way to go